# list model not getting return list

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview

I have one tabBase `Activity` and one `Fragment`. I am calling API in base `Activity` and passing that list data to `Fragment` using model list class. But i'm always getting getlist zero only. pls help me.

```
  public class ListTempStorage {

  private List<MyPojoClassList> listOne = new ArrayList<>();
  private List<MyPojoClassList> listTwo = new ArrayList<>();
  private List<MyPojoClassList> listThree = new ArrayList<>();


  public List<MyPojoClassList> getListOne() {
    return listOne;
  }
  public void setListOne(List<MyPojoClassList> listOne) {
    this.listOne = listOne;
  }
  public List<MyPojoClassList> getListTwo() {
    return listTwo;
  }

  public void setListTwo(List<MyPojoClassList> listTwo) {
    this.listTwo = listTwo;
  }


 }
```

**My `Fragment` class:**

```
 public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private ListTempStorage ourInstance;

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    init(v);

    return v;
   }
  private void init(View v) {
  ourInstance= new ListTempStorage ();

   try {

            List<MyPojoClassList> list = ourInstance.getListOne();
            if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {

                populateOpenAllLayout(list);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (OlabiConstant.IS_DEBUGGABLE) e.printStackTrace();
            activity.finish();

        }
```

Comment: This would be easier to read if it was indented properly.

Answer (score 1):

You will only get empty because you always populate your data when calling init in `onCreateView` with:

```
private void init(View v) {
  ourInstance= new ListTempStorage ();
}
```

You need to populate the data after you have it, create a method:

```
public void populate(ListTempStorage tempStorage) {
  ourInstance = tempStorage;
  // update your data here.
}
```

Then you can call the method fragment from your Base Activity.

Comment: am not understanding what u said,where i have to impliment this mehtod?activity or fragment?

Comment: you need to implement it in your fragment. Then call it from your activity where the fragment is hosted.